# Getting battery level in a Windows Phone 8 device?

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

How do I programatically get the battery level from a Windows Phone 8 device?

Comment: I don't think there's an API for it yet.

Comment: The only people who can answer this question are the people with NDAs telling them to not talk about this in a public forum :P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following works for me

*Windows.Phone.Devices.Power.Battery.GetDefault().RemainingChargePercent*

Comment: Documentation is available here: [Battery class (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207231)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the Battery level and the remaining time of the Windows Phone 8 device battery using the Battery class defined in the Windows.Phone.Devices.Power name space . Below are some examples of its usage.

1. [Retreiving the Remaining time of the Windows Phone 8 device battery
   programatically using C#](http://mobileosgeek.com/retreiving-the-remaining-time-of-the-windows-phone-8-device-battery-programatically-using-c/)
2. [How to retreive the Battery Level programatically in Windows Phone 8
   ?](http://mobileosgeek.com/how-to-retreive-the-battery-level-programatically-in-windows-phone-8/)